# Python 2.7 cannot find module when running py. But can find module in terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, import

OSX, PyCharm, with brew-installed python 2.7, simply trying to import

```
from azure.mgmt.common import SubscriptionCloudCredentials
import azure.mgmt.compute
import azure.mgmt.network
import azure.mgmt.resource
import azure.mgmt.storage
```

Got error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 XXX/pythonCode/p2.1/azure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX/pythonCode/p2.1/azure.py", line 9, in <module>
    from azure.mgmt.common import SubscriptionCloudCredentials
  File "XXX/pythonCode/p2.1/azure.py", line 9, in <module>
    from azure.mgmt.common import SubscriptionCloudCredentials
ImportError: No module named mgmt.common
```

Tried:

- Reinstall azure from source

  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python
- Running

  `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`

  I get 
  `['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']`

  In which `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` contains azure
- Running `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

  I get

  ```
  '', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.10.4/libexec/nose/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'
  ```

---

Remarkably
Running

`python -c "from azure.mgmt.common import SubscriptionCloudCredentials"`

in terminal does not error at all.

Can anyone explain where the problems are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the file in which you wrote your script in is called `azure.py`. This file is getting imported instead of the module `azure` that you installed, and it doesn't have the necessary attributes, resulting in this error.

Renaming the file your code is in to something else will fix this problem.

Comment: My gosh. Exactly. What was I thinking. Thank you ppperry.